# SQL Server Trigger not triggered after insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to copy the contents of a column into another column in the same table. Therefore, I created this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[kennscht_copy_to_prodverpt]
ON [dbo].[Stammdaten]
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Stammdaten
SET PRODVERPT = (SELECT KENNSCHT FROM INSERTED)
WHERE SNR = (SELECT SNR FROM INSERTED);
```

But when I use an UPDATE on the table to update `KENNSCHT` to a different value, `PRODVERPT` is not updated as well. Now, you could argue that is because the trigger is on `AFTER INSERT` and not `AFTER UPDATE`, but when I change it so it's triggered by `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, whenever I update any row, I get an error message from SQL Server

> Cannot update row because it would make the row not unique or update multiple rows (2 rows) [sic]

What is going on here? Either the trigger doesn't do anything, or it's messing up the whole table, making it un-updateable.

Update: I also tried the following trigger:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.PRODVERPT = i.KENNSCHT
FROM Stammdaten s
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.SNR = s.SNR;
```

But it has exactly the same behaviour. If I use only `AFTER INSERT`, nothing changes and if I use `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` I get the error message above.

Update 2: There are no multiple rows in the table, I already checked that because I thought it might be connected to the issue.

Comment: Your trigger is broken - it assumes that `inserted` only contains one row. It would be better to switch to the `FROM`/`JOIN` style of update so that you can `JOIN` with `inserted` but it doesn't seem like this is the *only* issue here because if it was causing you an issue, the error message would be about a subquery returning more than one value.

Comment: I tried a JOIN, too - but it has the same effect. As soon as I use "UPDATE" as the trigger, it gives me the error message.

Comment: Also add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the trigger.

Comment: @MartinSmith that solved it. I can now run the JOIN trigger. Thanks! Can you set it as an answer?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - `SET NOCOUNT ON` is included in TToni's answer as well. Plus that gives you the bonus of working if someone enables the recursive triggers database option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this trigger as an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, it runs recursively, since it always issues another UPDATE statement against the same table, which leads to another execution of the trigger.

To work around this, you either need to make the update trigger an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger or test if the `KENNSCHT` column was modified at all. For the latter you can use the `UPDATE()` function like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[kennscht_copy_to_prodverpt_after_update]
ON [dbo].[Stammdaten]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF (UPDATE(KENNSCHT))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE s
            SET s.PRODVERPT = i.KENNSCHT
            FROM Stammdaten s
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.SNR = s.SNR
    END
END
```

Comment: Recursive triggers aren't enabled by default and if that was the issue they would get a recursion limit exceeded error. The error mentioned in the question is one from the client tools when `NOCOUNT ON` isn't on.

Comment: I tried this step by step, but after I set the `NOCOUNT ON` inside the trigger, it already worked.

Comment: @Florian Pescka: Still I think it would be a good idea to use my code. It only issues another update if needed (not always, like the original code), and it is more robust because it still works if recursive triggers get enabled.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Thanks for the heads-up! I'll let the answer stand with this comment, it's already upvoted and I'll add another +1 to it.

Comment: Yes I still used your recommendation, I just wanted to point out that the actual error was the NOCOUNT.